# Using something other than a Frame for Window.Current.Content

Tags: uwp, window, frame

I am trying to create a top level navigation control in UWP. So far I was thinking of replacing the Window.Current.Content with my top level navigation control instead of a Frame. (My Control wraps a frame)

It works but now while deployed to a phone the status bar and virtual buttons overlap my content.

Has anyone had any success not using a Frame as their window's content?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't changed my content to other controls but it seems even using Frame you will get the same behavior on phone. To control this you may need to caculate the height of the status bar and virtual button then do some modification to change your UI to fit the content.
By the way, I have no idea why you need to use your control replce the frame. Using Frame you can still put your control on your frame and then keep the navigation history.

Comment: My control provides the top level up to perform the navigation. What I did to get this working as expected was to sub class page instead of control. Page seems to have some internal code to fit properly.

Comment: @RichardEagle Can you share your answer directly in this case?Which I think is more reasonable for others.